# Pygame Attribute Error "Pygame.rect"

Tags: python, button, attributes, pygame

> AttributeError: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'centre'

That is the error I get when i try to run my code, I am very new to python so it may be a rookie error and if it is I would appreciate an explanation on how to fix it. I am currently using a tutorial ([Tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/placing-text-pygame-buttons/)) on how to add text on to a button (#button), but to my current and very little knowledge when i try to centre the text around the buttons co-ordinates it gives me an attribute error. Any help is appreciated :) Thanks.

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

size = width, height = 720, 480
speed = [2, 2]


#Colours
black = (0,0,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
green = (0,200,0)
red = (200,0,0)
green_bright = (0,255,0)
red_bright = (255,0,0)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("BETA::00.0.1")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()


def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def game_intro():

    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Broom!", largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((width/2),(height/2))

intro = True

while intro:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(event)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    screen.fill(blue)

    screen.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    #Button

    if 75+100 > mouse[0] > 75 and 400+50 > mouse[1] > 400:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, green_bright,(75,400,100,50))
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, green,(75,400,100,50))

    smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",20)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("GO", smallText)
    TextRect.centre = ((75+(100/2)),(400+(50/2)))
    screen.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    if 550+100 > mouse[0] > 550 and 400+50 > mouse[1] > 400:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, red_bright,(550,400,100,50))
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, red,(550,400,100,50))

    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Exit", smallText)
    TextRect.centre = ((550+(100/2)),(400+(50/2)))
    screen.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(15)

game_intro()
```

Comment: You have a typo: not `centre`, but `center`

Comment: haha didn't see that, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by a typo. The name of the virtual attribute is `center` but not `centre`. See [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)